# How to express this statement into logical notation?

Tags: notation

Statement:
Natural numbers that are exactly divisible by 2 are not prime.

I got this:

∀n ∈ N,¬P(n)∧(n%4)

where P(n) is the predicate "n is a prime number"

and N is the set of natural numbers.

And how would I write this using implication?

Also, what would be the contrapositive and converse?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $\%$ symbol is a binary operator in programming that outputs an integer value: given integers $a, b$, $a \% b $ returns the remainder of $a/b$, i.e., is the modulus operator returning $a \pmod b$. So that is not appropriate here. We need an Boolean operator here that outputs true or false.

So we can use the $\mid$ symbol: for two integer values $a, b,\;\; a\mid b$ evaluates to true if $b \equiv 0 \pmod a$: if "a exactly divides b", and is false otherwise.

Given this, we can write your expression as $$\forall n \in \mathbb N\,\Big(2\mid n\rightarrow \lnot P(n)\Big)\tag{1}$$ or $$\forall n \Big((n\in \mathbb N \land 2\mid n)\rightarrow \lnot P(n)\Big)$$

Taking the **contrapositive** of the quantified expression in $(1)$ gives us $$\forall n \in \mathbb N\Big(P(n) \rightarrow (2 \not\mid n)\Big)\tag{contrapositive}$$

which reads "Every natural number that's prime is not exact divisible by 2."

The **converse** of the original expression is given by: $$\forall n \in \mathbb N\Big(\lnot P(n) \implies 2\mid n\Big)\tag{converse}$$

which reads: "Every natural number that's not prime is exactly divisible by 2."

Comment: $\ddot \smile$, @Amzoti!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what '%' means, but your statement reads "For all natural numbers $n$, $n$ is not prime and $n$%4".  This isn't exactly the statement you had in words.

Using implication:
$$ (n \in \mathbb{N} \wedge 2 \mid n) \implies \neg P(n), $$
where $P(n)$ is the predicate you defined.  Note that this isn't a true statement (2 is prime).

The contrapositive reads "If a natural number $n$ is prime, then $n$ is not exactly divisible by 2".

The converse reads "If a natural number $n$ is not prime, then $n$ is exactly divisible by 2".